# How to use Notification Center which counts number of events

Tags: iphone, background, notifications

Is there a way to get the number of times a notification was evoked?
The notification has to work in the background, like the Darwin Notification Center does, but unfortunately, this option ignores the last entry "CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold".
Can anyone help?
thank you

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                NULL, // observer
                                someCallBack, // callback
                                CFSTR("something happens"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

EDIT:

I am sorry for not having explained my problem with enaugh details, but i realised this when i got the first answer.
Assume my App is used and then the home button is pressed. So it will go into background. And if on the iphone the event "something happens" happens (even with my app running in background), the notification holds this information. But only ONCE, no matter how often the event happenend during my app is running in background. And i would like to know the exact number of events "something happens", that happened during the time my app ran in background. I hope i could make this clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make one global instance of int type. define it 0(Zero) in ViewDidLoad and increased by 1 when the method is called. it can count total no. of invoke.

For Eg.

in .h File

```
    int intCount;
```

.m file

```
     ViewDidLoad method
           intCount=0;
```

In your method

```
    intCount++;
```

you can print like

```
       NSLog(@"totalInvoke=%d",intCount);
```

Comment: sorry for stealing your time by not formulating the question good enaug... i have edited it

Answer (score 0):

When using Darwin Notification Center "CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter()" the 'object' and 'suspensionBehavior' arguments are ignored when calling CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(), so in your code CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold has no effect and it is recommended to pass 0 or NULL in ignored arguments to ensure future compatibility, hope this helps.